# go-аналог _kbhit() из c++

Tags: golang

```
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        switch (_getch())
        {
        // some code
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Привёл пример кода на c++, go знаю плохо, подскажите как на это можно реализовать на нём

Comment: есть пакет key - https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/event/key

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я помню, conio.h это заголовочный файл для консольного ввода вывода. Так что в общем виде можно представить программу на  Go так. ( я так понял что ф-ции _kbhint и _getc самописные. С крестами не очень знаком. )

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)
func main () {
    for _, arg := rang os.Args[1:]{
        if _kbhit(){
            switch .. :=  _getch {
                // some code
            }

        }
    }
}
```